# Successful match in Replace but not in Cases?

Tags: pattern-matching

I have a little example that exhibits a successful pattern match in `ReplaceAll` that `Cases` misses and I wonder if the assembled sages would be so kind as to offer me an explanation?

This is chopped from an original Prolog emulator by Renan Cabrera circa 2000.

```
ClearAll[k,s,l,m,j,f,w,g,a,b]
```

Consider an unordered sequence of *statements `s`* stored in a *knowledge base `k`*, each being a *predicate `l`* about some *terms `m`, `f`, `j`,* and *`w`*:

```
k=s[l[m,f],
    l[m,w],
    l[j,w],
    l[j,m]
];
```

We wish to search this knowledge base for any predicates such that `l[m,X_]` and `l[j,X_]`, where `X_` matches the same term in both predicates. Our first cut is something like

```
k /. s[l[m,X_],l[j,X_]] -> a[X]
(* Out[42]:= s[l[m,f],l[m,w],l[j,w],l[j,m]] *)
```

but this doesn't work until we make *s* flat and orderless (associative and commutative):

```
SetAttributes[s,{Flat,Orderless}]
```

and now

```
k /. s[l[m,X_],l[j,X_]] -> a[X]
(* Out[43]:= s[a[w],l[j,m],l[m,f]] *)
```

This is, of course, just the same as `ReplaceAll[k, s[l[m,X_],l[j,X_]] -> a[X]]`.
(notice the canonical reordering in the output), and now I can extract my answer with something like

```
Cases[k /. s[ l[m, X_], l[j, X_] ]->a[X],a[Y_]->Y]
(* Out[44]:= {w} *)
```

The surprise and the question is why doesn't this work?

```
Cases[k, s[ l[m, X_], l[j, X_] ] -> a[X]]
(* Out[45]:= {} *)
```

or even this

```
MatchQ[k, s[ l[m, X_], l[j, X_] ]]
(* Out[46]:= False *)
```

It's as though `ReplaceAll`, `Cases`, and `MatchQ` are using different pattern matchers.

Will be grateful for advice, clues, discussion, etc.

Comment: To me the interesting, and odd, result is not `Cases` or `MatchQ` but `ReplaceAll`. The only hint that I can find is that "ReplaceAll looks at each part of expr, tries all the rules on it, and then goes on to the next part of expr. The first rule that applies to a particular part is used; no further rules are tried on that part, or on any of its subparts." My guess is that this translates into somehow looking at all combinations of `s` with two arguments (due to `Flat`), one of them matches and is replaced by `a` and the whole thing is returned.

Comment: I think `Cases` simply does not take into account `Flat` and `Orderless`.  It just looks at the elements of the input expression one by one, unlike `ReplaceAll` which does consider `Flat` and `Orderless` too.  I realize this doesn't explain what happens, it merely re-states it.

Comment: @Szabolcs I thought that too. But try this Cases[Hold[3 + 4 + 5], X___ + 3 :> X, 2]

Comment: @belisarius You're right, even more convincing: `Cases[Hold[3 + 4 + 5], X___ + 4 :> X]`.  You could make an answer out of that, I think.

Comment: @Szabolcs It would be pretty ... but I don't yet understand why it does not work in the OP's problem ...

Comment: @Szabolcs, I think you are right. In your example `Cases` looks at the elements of the input expression one by one. The first element of `Hold[Plus[3,4,5]]` is `Plus[3,4,5]` which matches the pattern `Plus[X___,4]` with X = `Sequence[3,5]`. The result is `{3,5}` but this is not a list of 2 matches, it is a single match. If you use `X___+4:>a[X]` you will get `{a[3,5]}` rather than `{a[3],a[5]}`

Comment: I think this is probably a particular behaviour of `ReplaceAll` (or perhaps of those built-ins that don't search depth-first if there's any other). The title should probably be changed to `ReplaceAll`. Try `SetAttributes[f, Flat];replace=Replace[#1, #2, {0, Infinity}]&;Through@{replace, ReplaceAll}[f[1, 2, 3], f[2, 3]:>8]`. Can't test thoroughly right now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`MatchQ` looks to see if the whole expression matches the pattern, so you need to add a blank to allow for the other elements of s:

```
MatchQ[k, s[l[m, X_], l[j, X_], ___]]
```

`Cases` takes a list and checks each element in turn, so I think the pattern matcher only gets to see each `l[a,b]` in isolation. The best I could come up with is:

```
Cases[Subsets[k, {2}], s[l[m, X_], l[j, X_]] -> a[X]]
```

### Further investigation

Here are a couple of questions about `Cases` I have tried to answer experimentally. I don't know if this helps anyone else much, but it was useful for me to go through it and I think I now understand *how* `Cases` behaves, even if the *why* is a mystery.

Q1. Does `Cases` take into account `Orderless` ?

```
In[1]:= SetAttributes[a,{Orderless}]
In[2]:= Cases[a[x,y],a[y,_]->0,{0}]
Out[2]= {0}
```

A1. Yes, it does. The pattern matcher understands that `a[x,y] === a[y,x]` which matches the pattern.

Q2. Does `Cases` take into account `Flat` ?

```
In[3]:= SetAttributes[a,{Flat}]
In[4]:= Cases[a[x,y,z],a[onebit_,anotherbit_]:>{onebit+anotherbit},{0}]
Out[4]= {{a[x]+a[y,z]}}
```

A2. Yes, it does. The pattern matcher understands that `a[x,y,z] === a[a[x],a[y,z]]` which matches the pattern.

Q3. Given that `Cases` can use the above transformation, will it get a "hit" on the pattern a[x] ?

```
In[5]:= Cases[a[x,y,z],a[x]->b,{0,Infinity}]
Out[5]= {}
```

A3. No, even though the transformed expression `a[a[x],a[y,z]]` clearly contains a match for `a[x]` at level 1, this doesn't count. `Cases` appears to require the entire expression at level *n* to match the pattern. The logic appears to be:

- Level 0: expression `a[x,y,x]` does not match `a[x]`
- Level 0: transformed expression `a[a[x],a[y,z]]` does not match `a[x]`
- Level 1: expression `x` does not match `a[x]`
- Level 1: expression `y` does not match `a[x]`

etc...

This is in contrast to `ReplaceAll`, which *does* pick up the `a[x]` in the transformed expression:

```
In[6]:= a[x,y,z]/.a[x]->b
Out[6]= a[b,y,z]
```

So it seems like `ReplaceAll` applies `Flat` and `Orderless` transformations outermost, and then for each transformed expression it digs down into the subexpressions looking for a match. Whereas `Cases` digs down into the subexpressions of the untransformed original expression outermost, and for each subexpression it tries the various `Flat` and `Orderless` transformations looking for a match.

I realise this is probably a complete misrepresentation of how the pattern matcher *actually* works, but as a hand-waving mental picture it seems to explain the different behaviour of `Cases` and `ReplaceAll`

Comment: I think `Cases` is supposed to work with any head, not just List, as in `Cases[foo[bar, baz, qux], baz]` `~~>` `baz`. That's part of what led me to think the original idea `Cases[k,s[l[m,X_],l[j,X_]]->a[X]]` would work. I like your proposal, and note on the side that `Cases[k,s[l[m,X_],l[j,X_],___]->a[X]]` does not work. Still waiting for more explanation of what's going on with `Cases`.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin, `Cases` does work with any head. In your example `foo` is the head and it checks the individual elements `bar`, `baz` and `qux` against the pattern. When you try `Cases[k, ...]` the head is `s` and it checks the individual elements `l[m,f]`, `l[m,w]` etc against the pattern. There is no match because the pattern has head `s` but none of the individual elements under test have head `s`. Note that `Cases[k,s[_]]` also returns an empty list.

Comment: @SimonWoods This does not quite explain it, since first, you should have used `Cases[k,s[__]]`, and second, the zero-level spec, when provided, solves the problem here: `Cases[k, s[__], {0, Infinity}]`, but not in the original example.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, good point, thanks. I've done a bit of investigating and extended my answer.

Comment: @SimonWoods, thanks for the in-depth investigation. Short of an authoratative statement from Wolfram insiders, this answer gives me quite a lot of grist for the mill.

Comment: Simon, it is worth pointing out that your test `SetAttributes[a,{Orderless}]; Cases[a[x,y],a[y,x]->0,{0}]` doesn't actually tell us anything about `Cases`.  In this instance all the work is done by `Orderless` before `Cases` even sees it.  In fact because `Orderless` does all the work if we interfere with it we lose the match:  `Cases[a[x, y], HoldPattern[a[y, x]] -> 0, {0}]`.  On the other hand, when a `_` is involved the pattern matcher does the work:  `Cases[a[x, y], HoldPattern[a[y, _]] -> 0, {0}]`.  IMHO you should update your example.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thanks. I'll update the example.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect that the difference relates to the fact that `Cases` traverses depth-first, while `ReplaceAll` traverses breadth-first.  This can be seen here:

```
k = s[l[m, f], l[m, w], l[j, w], l[j, m]];
test = (Print[##]; False) &;

k /. x__?test :> Null;
```

> ```
> s[l[m,f],l[m,w],l[j,w],l[j,m]]
> s
> l[m,f]
> l
> m
> f
> l[m,w]
> l
> m
> w
> l[j,w]
> l
> j
> w
> l[j,m]
> l
> j
> m
> ```

```
Cases[k, x__?test, {0, -1}, Heads -> True];
```

> ```
> s
> l
> m
> f
> l[m,f]
> l
> m
> w
> l[m,w]
> l
> j
> w
> l[j,w]
> l
> j
> m
> l[j,m]
> s[l[m,f],l[m,w],l[j,w],l[j,m]]
> ```

Comment: +1 I always forget the handiness of "_?" for testing

Comment: @belisarius incidentally, in this application I could have used `?Print` instead of `?test` but I did not for the sake of clarity.