# Why the flat f[x] is treated as ghostHead_[f[x]]?

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching

While reading [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73017/5943) I feel confused. If we do not care any specific detail of the original question, then ybeltukov's answer essentially makes use of the following fact

```
h_[a___, G[x_, ___, y_], b___] ^:= y[x]
G[2, e]
```

> e[[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5024/5943)]

This example shows that unlike `Set`, `SetDelayed`, `TagSet` and `TagSetDelayed` which imperatively require that the assignment is associated to some *symbol* called *assignment tag*, `UpSet` and `UpSetDelayed` can be used to make assignment associated to *pattern object* as well (like the `h_` in this example).

However, when executing `G[2, e]` it seems that the evaluator treats the flat input `G[2, e]` as `ghostHead_[G[2, e]]` such that the user-defined `UpValues` for `G` can be applied.

I cannot understand this. I assume there is some very fundamental mechanism taking effect in this example. Could someone point out the missing knowledge?

---

### Edit

I am also confused about the use of `Simplify` in ybeltukov's answer. Why `Simplify` can reduce `G[2, e]` to `e[2]`? I have not found any documentation revealing this.

---

### Edit 2

As Szabolcs points out in the comment, because the `StandardForm` is by default used by the Front End for output, the plain input `G[2,e]` is evaluated to `G[2,e]` then wrapped as

```
StandardFrom[G[2,e]]
```

which applies to the `UpValues` defined by

```
h_[a___, G[x_, ___, y_], b___] ^:= y[x]
```

where, according to the standard Wolfram Language evaluation process, the `UpValues` of `G` is used prior to the `DownValues` of `StandardFrom`, so that the `DownValues` of `StandardFrom` is shadowed.

This is a side effect of the Front End wrapping `StandardForm` to the output, but we may make use of it.

We can also understand ybeltukov's answer which is,

```
h_[a___, G[x_, ___, y_], b___] ^:= h[a, y[x], b]
Simplify[G[2,e]]
```

> e[[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5024/5943)]

where `Simplify` also acts as a wrapper whose `DownValues` is also shadowed, and according to the upvalue definition, `Simplify[G[2,e]]` is evaluated as `Simplify[e[2]]` which further reduces to `e[2]` according to the definition of `Simplify`.

With such understanding, we can replace the `Simplify` with `StandardForm`,

```
StandardForm@G[2,e]
```

this will return the same result but with better efficiency, because `StandardForm` does not require searching for applicable transformation rules.

Comment: An insight: `h_[a___, G[x_, ___, y_], b___] ^:= (Print@Hold@h[a, G[x, y], b]; y[x])`

Comment: It is not possible to associate an assignment with a pattern object.  It must always be associated with a symbol.  Here that symbol is `G`.  The example you show creates an up-value of `G`.  So how come `G[2,e]` evaluates at all?  Since the definition is an up-value one, `G[2,e]` should only evaluate if it is wrapped by some head. Here it appears it isn't.  What really happens is that as part of formatting, the FrontEnd does wrap `G[2,e]` in another head, which then triggers the UpValue evaluation.  Running this example in a terminal, with no Front End, does nothing: `G[2,e]` doesn't evaluate.

Comment: I guess the morale is: UpValues of such generality are unsafe and are best avoided.

Comment: The mystery is where does the wrapper come from. It is almost certain that it is introduced by the Front End, but how and why? If we change the outermost head `h_` to some certain symbol `h`, ie, `h[a___, G[x_, ___, y_], b___] ^:= (Print@Hold@h[a, G[x, y], b]; y[x])` then the previous result `e[2]` is not obtained. This shows that the Front End picks the `ghostHead` it wraps to `G[2,e]`. There must be some mechanism used by the Front End, but the purpose is hidden.

Comment: @saturasl `G[2,e]` simply evaluates to itself.  But the Front End will format every output as StandardForm by default.  This formatting goes wrong and yields `e[2`] due to the UpValue

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you for the insight! This explains everything, since the output is wrapped as `StandardForm@G[2,e]` and the `UpValues` of `G` is applied. This side effect is not intended but we may be able to make use of it. You have my gratitude for helping me understand this.